# In Visual Studio Version (17.3.2 in this case) - Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "xxxx.pfx". Could not find the file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

"Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "xxxx.pfx". Could not find the file..."

The certificate is gone (not there or anywhere).

I have tried not signing the assembly, changing the strong name key, and creating a new one.

The project successfully builds in Debug mode but not in Release mode (expected).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can *you* find the key file "xxxx.pfx"? Is that the exact error message?

Comment: The key is gone. That is the problem. But changing it to another key or not signing is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to close the project.

Do a search in the .csproj file of the project folder using Visual Studio or Notepad ++ for the "xxx.pfx" string (substitute the xxx for the correct key filename).

If the string is found, back up this file, and then comment out or delete the line(s) that is/are pointing to the key.

Then reopen the project and confirm the problem is gone.

I hope this helps!